# Loop To Display Every Other Value

Tags: apex

Trying to make a loop in execute anonymous that displays every other value.

eg 1, 3, 5, 7 not 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

This is what I have so far but I feel like I might be off base:

```
List<Integer> count = new List {1,2,3,4,5};    
for (Integer i : count) {
    if (i  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you could go about this, but the way I'd go about this (if using a loop) is to use the `if()` to check for your *negative condition*, then use `continue;` to get to the next iteration of the loop.

This keeps the level of indentation in your code to a minimum (and less indentation in code is generally easier to understand)

```java
List<Integer> count = new List<Integer>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(Integer current :count){
    // Math.mod() is the modulus function
    // i.e. "what is the remainder"
    // x mod 2 = 0 when x is even, and 1 when x is odd
    if(Math.mod(current, 2) == 0){
        continue;
    }

    system.debug(current);
}
```

Comment: thank you! I confused myself and ended up in a tizzy

Answer (score 0):

Better use `basic for loop` and use `2 step increment` that way you don't need to add any condition inside loop.

Like this:

```
List<Integer> count = new List {1,2,3,4,5};
Integer numbersCount = count.size();

for(Integer i = 0; i < numbersCount; i += 2){
    System.debug(count[i]);
}
```